# Replace multiple line code inside square brackets through sed

Tags: linux, sed

This is the content of a js file, want to append a value by putting a comma to last value.

> Input

```
TRIVIAL_TIMES: [
 'tags',
 'users',
 'jobs',
 'teams'
],
```

> Output:

```
TRIVIAL_TIMES: [
 'tags',
 'users',
 'jobs',
 'teams',
 'more'
],
```

> sed -i "{ N;N;N;N; s/TRIVIAL_TIMES:.*/TRIVIAL_TIMES:\n\t'tags',\n\t'users',\n\t'jobs',\n\t'teams',\n\t'more'/}"  filename.js

This works fine, if there is no content above the TRIVIAL_TIMES, otherwise gives some inconsistent result by duplicating the value. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: I have added my workaround.

Comment: Did `sed "/^TRIVIAL_TIMES:/{N;N;N;N;s/..*/&,\n\t'more'/}" file` work for you? Or what did?